# threads package for python3.6

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, package

This is what I encountered when trying to import thread package:

`>>> import thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packag
es/thread.py", line 3
    print('This is ultran00b's package - thread')`

I tried uninstalling and install again but it won't work.

Comment: The `thread` module has been renamed `_thread` in python 3  - its a low-level module generally not intended for use directly. You've installed some other package that includes a `thread` module. Whoever this _ultran00b` is has done a disservice by naming his/her module "thread" and installing it into the top level namespace. Bad Noob!

Answer (score 1):

thread module was deprecated in python 3. Try threading instead:

```
import threading
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import the thread class ?

Use :

```
from threading import Thread
```

Comment: `>>> import threading` makes exactly same error. I did `pip3 uninstall thread` and then `pip3 install Thread` and `import threading` worked finally. It is weird why I can not install `threading` itself